# How to create an Android http server to serve media files for streaming in a web browser or chrome cast?

Tags: android, video, stream, sd-card, chromecast

I was trying to stream a video file from sd card to a chrome cast device. I made an http server with the following source.

https://github.com/joinAero/AndroidWebServ

But i can't stream video files greater than 50 MB. Also unable to seek the stream. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Background on streaming media ( before you get to android specific issues )

Client to server should include headers with the GET media request...

```
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Content-Type: $Mimetype-for-media
> Expect: 100-continue
```

Server to client headers and protocol will be something you don't have to look into when on ( apache or nginx with http 1.1 )

nginx/apache will first send response headers:

```
< Content-Type: $Mime
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The client and server will agree on chunked encoding with a continue protocol :

```
* Done waiting for 100-continue
```

and then the server just does io according to the protocol until end-of-stream which it alerts with an "END" signal corresponding to the protocol.

see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Encoded_data) or read the [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-7.2) for the details of what the server sends to indicate $END...

When you have written the last segment of the media file to the server's output, send an END signal per the protocol for 'chunked-encoding'...

```
private static final byte[] FINAL_CHUNK = new byte[] { '0', '\r', '\n', '\r', '\n' };

$myConnection.getResponse().getOutputStream().write(FINAL_CHUNK).
```

If your android server implements the protocol then it will not be any different from apache/nginx serving chunked media on http. it will just work.